# Check if argument is a file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to check if an argument is a directory or a file. I want to put a / after each directory name and a * after every executable file. I know ls uses -F to get this information but I can't figure this out in my script.

Here is my code:

```
    echo -n "Please enter Directory name you wish to search: "
read dir

for filename in "/home/me/Desktop/$dir"/*

do

    if (-F $filename)
    then 
    echo $filename

    fi
done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`[ -f "$filename" ]` is true for files, `[ -d "$dirname" ]` is true for directories.

Comment: I mean there no error but it does not display "/" for directory and "*" for a file, as it does when I just type ls -F. Any ideas ? ?

Comment: `do

if [ -d $filename ]; then
    echo $filename
elif [ -f $filename ]; then
    echo $filename
fi
done`

Comment: @Tomala: `if [ -d "$filename" ] ; then echo "$filename"/ ; elif [ -f "$filename" ] ; then echo "$filename"'*' ; fi`

Comment: Ok got it, I thought it could be done automatically as it is with ls -F. Thanks anyway !